# How to use the value of Jquery script in Django Form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, django-templates

I have a follwoing Jquery code, which create a `Time Picker`:

```
<input class="time" type="text" name="start" id="start" />
$('input.time').timepicker();
```

And i want to use this time picker value which comes into the text in Django-Forms.

My `models.py`:

```
class UsertTime(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=False)
data = models.CharField(max_length=30)
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

my `forms.py`:

```
class UserTimeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = UserTime
```

In my `template.html`:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="{% trans "Add " %}" /> <a href="{% url host_list %}">{% trans "Cancel" %}</a>
</form>

<input class="time" type="text" name="start" id="start" />
$('input.time').timepicker();
```

Now how should i fill the `timestamp` Field by the `Jquery` written input. Following is the refer link for the Jquery Code:

> [Link for the Jquery sample](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/timepicker)

Comment: I think you should be able to change your selector from $('input.time') to a selector that will match the input rendered by {{ form.as_p }}.  It is just rendering an input of type text for that piece of data, which the datepicker will work with.

Comment: @Gromer: Yeh, you are right, but the problem is How i should use {{form.as_p}} timestamp field with this.timepicker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless, I'm gravely misunderstanding you, just use `val()`:

```
$('#id_timestamp').val($('#time').val())
```

Comment: Thanks for the replying @Chris but How should i integrate it with Django Forms. I mean it *** {{ form.as_p }} ***. And you can see the Django Form class. So how should i use it? I am not the best in Django. Would you please update the code according to it.

Comment: That sets the value of the timestamp field to the value of the other field. Django just processes the form as normal. Not sure what more you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I might also be misunderstanding; but, can you not just inspect the output of `form.as_p` and operate on that input instead of `$('input.time')`

```
$('#id_timestamp').timepicker()
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this not work:

```
<input class="time" type="text" name="start" id="start" value="{{form.timestamp}}" />
```

Sorry, I'm not an expert in Django.